# Get row-index of the last non-NaN value in each column of a pandas data frame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, scipy, nan

How can I return the row index location of the last non-nan value for each column of the pandas data frame and return the locations as a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html#pandas.notnull) and specifically [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax) to get the index values of the non `NaN` values

```
In [22]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,NaN], 'b':[NaN, 1,NaN, 3]})
df
Out[22]:
    a   b
0   0 NaN
1   1   1
2   2 NaN
3 NaN   3
In [29]:

df[pd.notnull(df)].idxmax()
Out[29]:
a    2
b    3
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

Actually as correctly pointed out by @Caleb you can use [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) which is designed for this:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,1,2,np.NaN], 'b':[np.NaN, 1,np.NaN, -1]})
df

Out[3]:
    a   b
0   3 NaN
1   1   1
2   2 NaN
3 NaN  -1

In [6]:
df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

Out[6]:
a    2
b    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This does not seem to address the question. Doesn't this give you the index locations of the maximum values of each column? Not the last value, as the op is asking?

Comment: @Caleb good point, have updated my answer using `last_valid_index` is the correct method here

Comment: Oh, I provided another answer, but I think yours is nicer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with non numeric values as well? I'd like to get the first instance of a value within a column

Comment: @RyanDavies this will work with mixed dtype columns, if you want the first instance then call `first_valid_index`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the row index of the last non-nan (and non-none) value, here is a one-liner:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':[5,1,2,NaN], 
        'b':[NaN, 6,NaN, 3]})

>>> df
    a   b
0   5 NaN
1   1   6
2   2 NaN
3 NaN   3

>>> df.apply(lambda column: column.dropna().index[-1])
a    2
b    3
dtype: int64
```

Explanation:

`df.apply` in this context applies a function to each column of the dataframe. I am passing it a function that takes as its argument a column, and returns the column's last non-null index.